# Embedded PDF prints off-center

Tags: pdf, printing, embed

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="filename.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

I can embed a PDF file into a web page using the simple code above.  But when I go to print the web page (using CTRL+P), only half the PDF appears on the print preview as it has been off-centred.  The same happens on this web page: http://pdfobject.com/examples/simplest-full-window.html.

Here is an example of a 'Print Version' web page where the embedded PDF centres when it is printed (CTRL+P): http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/our_paella_92328.pdf.  This example is also responsive, which is useful as the print appearance remains consistent no matter the size of the browser window.

Firstly how do I centre the embedded PDF upon printing? Secondly, how do I make the embedded PDF responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to print an embedded PDF, you must use the print command from the PDF plugin, not the print command from the web browser.

In the first example the Javascript code loads the PDF plugin and replaces the HTML document with the PDF document. If you hit CTRL+P then the print dialog from Internet Explorer is shown. If you click into the PDF plugin then press CTRL+P, then the print dialog from Adobe PDF plugin is shown.

In second example you open directly the PDF file. In this case the PDF plugin is loaded and activated automatically. No need to click in it. Pressing CTRL+P brings its own print dialog.